# How to return the object tree from a query from Neo4j Graphenedb to C#

Tags: c#, neo4j, uwp, neo4jclient, graphenedb

I doing a query on Neo4j on GrapheneDB, but it returns all combinations of match, 
so I have this tree:

[image: Tree]

But when I query it, it returns as a list of combinations of all paths, like a combinational table (even in the JSON view):

[image: table]

I need the nested tree objects, so I can bind it easily on UWP interface, something like:
[Using Cypher to return nested, hierarchical JSON from a tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34234373/using-cypher-to-return-nested-hierarchical-json-from-a-tree)

I used this command:

```
MATCH (p:Pessoa)-[ev:VENDA]-(y)-[e1]-(itemdopedido)-[e2]-(itemdoestoque) 
CALL apoc.convert.toTree(p) yield value
RETURN value;
```

but I get this error:

> ERROR Neo.ClientError.Procedure.ProcedureNotFound There is no procedure with the name `apoc.convert.toTree` registered for this database instance. Please ensure you've spelled the procedure name correctly and that the procedure is properly deployed.

On C# I created my Classes for the Vertexes and Edges:

```
public class Pedido
{
    public string since { get; set; }
}

public class ItemDoPedido
{
    public double ValorUnitario { get; set; }
}

public class ItemDoEstoque
{
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public string UnidadeDeMedida { get; set; }
}

public class Pessoa
{
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    //public string Telefone { get; set; }
    public string Facebook { get; set; }
}
```

Then I tried to use some Grouping:

```
var results = query.Results.GroupBy(
                    q => new { q.Pessoa, q.Pedido, q.ItemDoPedido, q.ItemDoEstoque }

                )
                .Select(y => new
                {
                    Pessoa = y.Key.Pessoa,
                    Venda = y.Key.Pedido//,                        
                    //Children = y.ToList()
                }
                );
            ;
```

but I think it is getting complicated, I prefer that the Object tree comes ready from the Server Query.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it can't find the procedure, probably because APOC is not installed. You can add APOC to GrapheneDB from the Extensions management view. More info [here](https://docs.graphenedb.com/docs/stored-procedures#section-adding-apoc)

Comment: I did that, enabled it, restarted server, but now the server gives Internal Server Error.

Comment: Neo4j can't start because the APOC version is probably too old. Just download the latest release and try again.

Comment: I followed that link and I was using https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures/releases/tag/3.1.3.9
now I will try https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures/releases/download/3.3.0.2/apoc-3.3.0.2-all.jar

Comment: Yes, that version is quite old and won't work for newer versions of Neo4j.